# How do I manually autowire a bean with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a bean `B` which I have to create myself (using `new B()`) and which has `@Autowire` and `@PostConstruct` annotations.

How do I make Spring process these annotations from my bean `A`?

Related question:

- [In Spring, can I autowire new beans from inside an autowired bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383205/in-spring-can-i-autowire-new-beans-from-inside-an-autowired-bean)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Aaron, I believe that your code is correct but I used the following:

```
B bean = new B();
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
factory.autowireBean( bean );
factory.initializeBean( bean, "bean" );
```

The first method will process `@Autowire` fields and methods (but not classic properties). The second method will invoke post processing (`@PostConstruct` and any defined `BeanPostProcessor`s).

Application context can be obtained in a bean if it implements `ApplicationContextAware` interface.

Comment: Maybe my code is wrong. `processInjection()` will only fill `@Autowired` fields while your code should process `@PostConstruct`, too (at least according to the JavaDoc). :-/

Comment: Does it also create a dynamic proxy, if the class has been annotated with `@Transactional` annotation for example?

Comment: @jeromerg No. Since the bean was created with `new`, there is no way for Spring to replace the instance with a proxy. The solution here is to move all the `@Transactional` methods into a helper bean which you inject into `B`.

Comment: This method still works as of 11-March-2021. Saved my day even after 9 years of OP.

Comment: I think the missing piece is that `initializeBean()` returns the proxied version, so the last line should be: `bean = factory.initializeBean( bean, "bean" );`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to let the spring container create automatically a new bean (instead of creating a new instance yourself with the new keyword).
Inside a class that needs to instantiate a new been programmatically, inject an instance of
***AutowireCapableBeanFactory*** :

```
@Autowired
private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;
```

Then:

```
B yourBean = beanFactory.createBean(B.class);
```

The container will inject instances annotated with @Autowired annotations as usual.