# Bean injection inside a JPA @Entity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa

Is it possible to inject beans to a JPA `@Entity` using Spring's dependency injection?

I attempted to @Autowire ServletContext but, while the server did start successfully, I received a NullPointerException when trying to access the bean property.

```
@Autowired
@Transient
ServletContext servletContext;
```

Comment: I was also facing the same kind of problem while injecting EntityManager into an EntityListener and found a solution and have answered it on another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171221/how-to-inject-entitymanager-in-entitylisteners/42222592#42222592

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can inject dependencies into objects not managed by the Spring container using `@Configurable` as explained here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable.

As you've realized by now, unless using the `@Configurable` and appropriate AspectJ weaving configuration, Spring does not inject dependencies into objects created using the `new` operator. In fact, it doesn't inject dependencies into objects unless you've retrieved them from the `ApplicationContext`, for the simple reason that it simply doesn't know about their existence. Even if you annotate your entity with `@Component`, instantiation of that entity will still be performed by a `new` operation, either by you or a framework such as Hibernate. Remember, annotations are just metadata: if no one interprets that metadata, it does not add any behaviour or have any impact on a running program.

All that being said, I strongly advise against injecting a `ServletContext` into an entity. Entities are part of your domain model and should be decoupled from any delivery mechanism, such as a Servlet-based web delivery layer. How will you use that entity when it's accessed by a command-line client or something else not involving a ServletContext? You should extract the necessary data from that ServletContext and pass it through traditional method arguments to your entity. You will achieve a much better design through this approach.

Comment: Both answers on this question are a perfect example of a useful SO thread (I upvoted both). While @RaviThapliyal 's answer below provides a way to achieve the result, your answer provides contextual background (for me it was an "aha"-experience that helped transforming all the theoretical info about Spring's DI that I've read in the past weeks into practically applicable knowledge). Imo there can't be enough of such posts on SO, because they actually **teach** something (and more often than not don't earn you much rep.)

Comment: @sthzg When I feel down and need to regain my confidence, I come back here and read your comment. Thank you.

Comment: Great answer. I'm just trying to inject gson so I have one instance across app. If this means I have to use/get to learn AspectJ so much the better, as the point of my project is to develop as many features and learn as much as I can while striving for efficiency and elegance. Not sure if AspectJ is overkill and costs performance to just instantiating new gson's but it's worth all things considered

Answer (score 21):

Yes, of course you can. You just need to make sure the entity is also registered as a Spring managed bean either declaratively using `<bean>` tags (in some spring-context.xml) or through annotations as shown below.

Using annotations, you can either mark your entities with `@Component` (or a more specific stereotype `@Repository` which enables automatic exception translation for DAOs and may or may not interfere with JPA).

```
@Entity
@Component
public class MyJAPEntity {

  @Autowired
  @Transient
  ServletContext servletContext;
  ...
}
```

Once you've done that for your entities you need to configure their package (or some ancestor package) for being scanned by Spring so that the entities get picked up as beans and their dependencies get auto wired.

```
<beans ... xmlns:context="..." >
  ...
  <context:component-scan base-package="pkg.of.your.jpa.entities" />
<beans>
```

***EDIT** : (what finally worked and why)*

- Making the `ServletContext` *static*. (remove *@Autowired*)

  ```
  @Transient
  private static ServletContext servletContext;
  ```

Since, JPA is creating a separate entity instance i.e. not using the Spring managed bean, it's required for the *context* to be shared.

- Adding a *@PostConstruct* `init()` method.

  ```
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
      log.info("Initializing ServletContext as [" +
                  MyJPAEntity.servletContext + "]");
  }
  ```

This fires `init()` once the Entity has been instantiated and by referencing `ServletContext` inside, it forces the injection on the *static* property if not injected already.

- Moving `@Autowired` to an *instance* method but setting the *static* field inside.

  ```
  @Autowired
  public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
      MyJPAEntity.servletContext = servletContext;
  }
  ```

Quoting my last comment below to answer why do we have to employ these shenanigans:

> There's no pretty way of doing what you want since JPA doesn't use the Spring container to instantiate its entities. Think of JPA as a separate ORM container that instantiates and manages the lifecycle of entities (completely separate from Spring) and does DI based on entity relationships only.

Comment: Unfortunately, `servletContext` is still null after adding `@Component` to the entity and `<context:component-scan>` to `app-config.xml`.

Comment: Make it static. `private static ServletContext servletContext;` If it's still `null` force the injection by defining a `@PostConstruct public void init() { log.info("Initializing ServletContext as [" + MyJPAEntity.servletContext + "]"); }` Hope this helps.

Comment: It is still null after making it `static`.  I think I am confused about what the `@PostConstruct` does.

Comment: `@PostConstruct` fires init() once the Entity has been instantiated and by referencing servletContext in it, it forces the injection on the (now static) property for the instance created. `static` was added to make sure it's shared since JPA is creating a separate entity instance i.e. not using the Spring managed bean.

Comment: From the server log: `Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields`.  I tried taking away the `@Autowire`, but even with the `@PostConstruct` servletContext is still null.  Maybe it can't do it because it is not a Spring managed bean?

Comment: Add the `@Autowire` to an *instance* method `public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext)` but set the static field inside. `@PostConstruct` won't work alone. No, it is a Spring managed bean but it's not being used by JPA and that's why we're trying to pass the context via a shared `static` field.

Comment: There's no pretty way of doing what you want since JPA doesn't use the Spring container to instantiate its entities. Think of JPA as a separate ORM container that instantiates and manages the lifecycle of entities (completely separate from Spring) and does DI based on entity relationships only.

Comment: Can you throw your last comment in the answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @mattblang Updated my answer with all the relevant comments above.

Comment: I consider it a code smell when you have to inject other beans inside your JPA entities and I think it is better to reconsider redesigning your entity and it's surrounding (package-private) classes, instead of injecting other beans inside your entity.

Answer (score 1):

After a long time I stumbled across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965771/587641) that made me think of an elegant solution:

- Add to your entities all the @Transient @Autowired fields you need
- Make a @Repository DAO with this autowired field:

  `@Autowired private AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowirer;`
- From your DAO, after fetching the entity from DB, call this autowiring code:

  `String beanName = fetchedEntity.getClass().getSimpleName();
  autowirer.autowireBean(fetchedEntity);
  fetchedEntity = (FetchedEntity) autowirer.initializeBean(fetchedEntity, beanName);`

Your entity will then be able to access the autowired fields as any @Component can.