# Spring JPA one to many denormalized count field

Tags: spring, jpa, denormalization

I have two entities, Books and Comments, in a one to many relationship (one book can have many comments). I want to be able to list books and number of comments about a book. I want it denormalized, meaning the books entity will have a counter that has number of comments for that book, and it will be updated every time a comment is entered (just playing with the concept, no need to discuss about the need of denormalizing here).

I think (correct me if I am wrong) this could be easily done with a trigger in the database (whenever a new comment is created, update a counter in the books table to the corresponding bookId), but for the sake of learning I want to do it through JPA, if it makes sense.

What I have so far: //omitted some annotations, just general info

Boks entity:

```
@Entity 
public class Books {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String author;
    private Long numComments;

  // getters and setters...
}
```

Comments entity:

```
@Entity
public class Comments {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String comment;
    private Long authorId;
    private Long bookId;

  // getters and setters...
}
```

Books repository: I added here a query to perform the update

```
/**
 * Spring Data JPA repository for the Books entity.
 */
public interface BooksRepository extends JpaRepository<Books,Long>         {
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Books v SET v.numComments = v.numComments + 1 WHERE v.id = :bookId")
int updateCounter(@Param("bookId")Long bookId);

}
```

And now the question: What next? I think I can put the update of the Books entity annotating with @PostPersist a method of the entity Comments, but I have been unsuccessful so far. I can imagine something like this:

```
    @PostPersist  //This function in the entity Comments
    protected void updateBooks() {
        //Likely some call to the repository here that updates the count
        //   in books the info we have from current entity.
    }
```

Any idea on how to do this? Some best practices about this kind of denormalization in JPA? Better to use the database triggers?

Answer (score 1):

spring not managed your entity classes and your idea is possible but you must inject `BooksRepository` in enttiy class then stay at you get Nullpointerexception because spring not managed enttiy classes,The reason your `BooksRepository` not initlaized, try  also read this post [Bean injection inside a JPA @Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471636/bean-injection-inside-a-jpa-entity) and anotate entity class `@Configurable` after

try this

```
@PostPersist 
protected void updateBooks(Comments comment) {

    int totalComment = BooksRepository.updateCounter(comment.getBookId());

    System.out.println(totalComment); // see totalComment in console
}
```

but good aprroach in service classes after call `updateCounter` when insert comment

example in your CommendService : when try a insert commend after call your  `updateCounter`

```
    if(comment.getBookId() != null) //Simple Control
     {

        CommentRepository.save(comment);
        BooksRepository.updateCounter(comment.getBookId());
    }
```