# Hibernate - populating autowired fields on load

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a prototype entity bean with multiple fields and 2 transient ones. Of these one is prototype as well and other is singleton.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
class A{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @Autowired
    @Transient
    private CacheA cache; //Prototype bean for caching some calc results

    @Autowired
    @Transient
    private ServiceA service; //Singleton service bean

}
```

Everything works until I try to read instance from database, because when Hibernate creates instance, Spring wont autowire any field.

Some additional info: I'm using CrudRepository and hibernate autoconfigured by spring-boot.

How do I properly solve such case? Is this intended behaviour, or should I make some additional configuration for hibernate to use spring context?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, your problem is same as in this question:

[Bean injection inside a JPA @Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471636/bean-injection-inside-a-jpa-entity)

Have a look at this. I am sure, it will help.

Comment: It appears to be the only way, at least only one I found. But I think it will make for cleaner solution if I properly separate all logic into services and make entities pojos. To be honest I was sure that there should be some way to make hibernate get bean from context. Anyway, thanks, I'll wait some more though, maybe someone knows different solution.

Comment: Yes, definitely.