# Spring @Autowire with Quartz

Tags: java, spring, annotations

In my web app I have a class like this, in which dao gets autowired and works fine

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/devicecontrolpanel")
public class DeviceCtrlPanelController {


@Autowired
private DeviceDao dao;
```

then in the same package I have this class

```
@WebListener
public class QuartzListener extends QuartzInitializerListener {

@Autowired
private DeviceDao dao;
```

Why isnt dao getting Autowired here? The job itself is starting. I want to pass that dao to my job

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    System.out.println("autowired works?");
    if(dao==null)
        System.out.println("dao is null");
    super.contextInitialized(sce);
    ServletContext ctx = sce.getServletContext();
    StdSchedulerFactory factory = (StdSchedulerFactory) ctx.getAttribute(QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);
    try {
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.getContext().put("aService", dao);
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(RegisterLog.class).build();
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("simple").withSchedule(
                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")).startNow().build();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        scheduler.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ctx.log("There was an error scheduling the job.", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a @WebListener is not a spring managed bean, so autowiering does not work here.

Comment: I had trouble using WebListener and Component annotations on the same bean. I got past it by using Spring's Scheduled annotation instead of WebListener to schedule my task.

Answer (score 1):

`@WebListener` is annotation from `javax.servlet` package so it won't `@Autowire` any component.

Anotate `QuartzListener` with `@Component` to tell Spring is a bean.

```
@WebListener
@Component
public class QuartzListener extends QuartzInitializerListener {

    @Autowired
    private DeviceDao dao;

}
```

**UPDATE**

> I already tried adding @Component annotation. Nothing changes. 
>   If adding the `@Component` annotation does not work try:

1. Try other `Spring` annotations `@Service`, `@Controller` or `@Repository`.
2. [manually autowiring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965600/how-do-i-manually-autowire-a-bean-with-spring).
3. Get a `DeviceCtrlPanelController` instance in `QuartzListener` and use the autowired `DeviceDao`.

Comment: I already tried adding @Component annotation. Nothing changes.

Comment: @Piotr Czapla Enable component scanning in spring context to make the '@Component'.

Answer (score 0):

@Autowiring happens between two classes which are configured as beans in spring.

`QuartzListener is not configured as a bean`, so no autowiring is happening inside it.

Put either of the annotations below on QuartzListener, based on its purpose to configure it as a bean:

```
1) @Component,
2) @Service,
3) @Controller
4) @Repository
```

Enable @Component scanning in spring-config.xml by:-

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your_package" />
```