# AutowireCapableBeanFactory: How to initialize primitive properties

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have some programmatically created beans that I am initializing via `AutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean()` as shown below:

spring.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="MyService" class="...">
        <property name="someProp" value="primitiveValue"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="MyBean" class="...">
        <property name="someString" value="primitiveValue"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

MyBean.java

```
public class MyBean implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired MyService myService;

    private String someString;
    public void setSomeString (String someString) {
        this.someString = someString;
    }
    public void afterPropertiesSet () {}
}
```

Caller:

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean(arg1, arg2, arg3);
autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(bean);
```

This correctly autowires `bean.myService` as expected. However it does not populate primitive properties like `bean.someString`.

Looking at the docs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965771/1800023), I though something like this would work:

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean(arg1, arg2, arg3);
autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(bean);
autowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(bean, "name");
```

But alas, `someString` is still `null`. I have found lots of references stating what *will not* work to initialize class properties, but nothing showing what *will* work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found I could use `AutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPropertyValues()` to accomplish what I wanted. Code to inject both `@Autowired` beans and primitive properties looks like this:

```
@Autowired AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

...

MyBean bean = new MyBean();
beanFactory.autowireBean(bean);
beanFactory.applyBeanPropertyValues(bean, bean.getClass().getSimpleName());
```